# Acer Aspire power management

Tags: power-management, battery, hibernate

I'm working to fix my Acer Aspire One netbook so that power management is working.

Currently, it goes to "suspend" when either the lid is closed or it is idle.

However, it must still be using significant power, if I open the lid after 24 hours it is dead (I have an extended 4-hour battery).

I followed the steps in:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/

That enabled the "Hibernate" option from the "gear cog" in the upper right corner, and that works.

It does **not** hibernate when the lid is closed.

I got greedy and when editing "logind.conf"  I also tried changing:

```
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
```

to

```
#IdleAction=hibernate
#IdleActionSec=1min
```

(I figured I'd test it, then change it back to 30 minutes... changed it back, still not working)

1)  Any further suggestions to enable the computer to Hibernate when closing the lid and when left idle?

Comment: may i ask, what  `cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode` tells you ? if it says 0 , create file `/etc/sysctl.d/laptop.conf` and add line vm.laptop_mode=5 , like shown [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_saving#Kernel_parameters). Let me know if this works

Answer (score 1):

1. **Re-enable hibernate**

   - **`su`**
   - **`cd /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/`**
   - **`gedit com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`**
   - **Copy and paste below lines** into the file and save it.

     > ```
     > [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
     > Identity=unix-user:*
     > Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
     > ResultActive=yes
     >
     > [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
     > Identity=unix-user:*
     > Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
     > ResultActive=yes
     > ```
2. **Hibernate your laptop when lid is closed:**

   - **`su`**
   - **`sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`**
   - In `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` look for **`HandleLidSwitch=suspend` and change it to `HandleLidSwitch=hibernate`** and save the file.
   - **Restart your computer** to apply changes or run `sudo restart systemd-logind`